# How can implement long running process in spring hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

as we know the struts interceptor execute and wait will take care of long running process by not getting the request to timeout and destroy it sends wait and at last the desired response i want to implement the same for long running process in spring and hibernate.

Comment: Struts just eases the development of the web application. What you're looking for here is how to start an asynchronous task, that's **completely irrelevant** for struts. I recommend you to take a look at [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use DeferredResult of Spring. It´s a Future implementation, that use the http long poling technique.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html

So let´s says that you will make a request, and the server it will return you the deferredResult, and then your request will keep it open until the internal process(Hibernate) finish his task. The timeout is configurable in the constructor.

Here another example http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing-in-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the session open throughout the lifetime of a request we tie it to the view. This is done either by using Spring's [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) or [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)

An open session in view filter will ensure that the Hibernate session is kept open all the way up to the rendering of the view.

Or

You can use a task queue in the backend for a long running process like [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html).

Work Queues (aka: Task Queues) is to avoid doing a resource-intensive task immediately and having to wait for it to complete. Instead the tasks are scheduled to be done later. Task is encapsulated as a message and sent to a queue. A worker process running in the background will pop the tasks and eventually execute the job. When you run many workers the tasks will be shared between them.

This concept is especially useful in web applications where it's impossible to handle a complex task during a short HTTP request window.